# "Expected expression in list of expressions"

Tags: ios, xcode7.3, swift2

I am trying to use some code to make a beginner app using Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.2 but I keep coming across the same problem. I have used similar code before but this just won't work. The error messages that come up are "Expected ',' separator" and when I do the fix it the same message comes up again and again. I also get "Expected expression in list of expressions" and "missing argument for parameter 'action' in call".They are all caused by the same line

```
   button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
```

Here is the code

```
import UIKit

class RatingControl: UIView {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
        addSubview(button)
    }

    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 240, height: 44)
    }

    func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {
        print("Button pressed")
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line does the error message appear?  This code compiles without trouble on my system.

Comment: `#selector` is Swift 2.2 which comes with Xcode 7.3 - maybe you have to update Xcode?

Comment: @ScottThompson it appears on the line starting button.addTarget the error is caused by action:

Comment: @EricD. Just tried. The #selector is now coloured so that's good but the same errors still come up.

Comment: Your Xcode is confused after the upgrade. Help it: "Product > Clean" and also clean the "derived data". It should do the trick.

Comment: @EricD. Thank you my code is now properly working.

Answer (score 6):

You need to *Clean* the project.

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following code:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "ratingButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
```

Answer (score 1):

`#selector` is Swift 2.2 which comes with Xcode 7.3, so you have to update Xcode to the latest version.

Once done, if your Xcode is confused after the upgrade, help it: go to menu "Product > Clean", and also clean the "derived data" folder if necessary.

*Note: this is an answer made from my comments to OP which solved their issue.*

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I had created the UIButton like this:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size, height: size)
```

For me the error went away when I changed how the button was created:

```
let button = UIButton(type: .System)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size, height: size)
```

Neither cleaning the project nor deleting derived data fixed the issue for me. I was using Xcode 7.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

You should clean the projects:

Product -> Clean

Answer (score 0):

The my code is true with a code:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "ratingButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
```

but, what diferente bettwen action: String and action: #selector

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).